# Fabric maven repo causes slow gradle builds

Tags: android, maven, gradle, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

After upgrading from using the Crashlytics maven repo to the new Fabric maven repo and gradle plugin, my gradle builds have become incredibly slow.

The problem seems to be caused by the Fabric maven repo returning a 401 unauthorized error whenever gradle tries to resolve a dependency:

```
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/google/android/gms/play-services/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/support-annotations/21.0.2/support-annotations-21.0.2.pom]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/19.0.1/mediarouter-v7-19.0.1.pom]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/support-annotations/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized: https://maven.fabric.io/repo/com/google/android/gms/play-services/maven-metadata.xml]
```

The old Crashlytics maven repo did not return these results.

Has anyone had a similar error, or found a fix?

Comment: Not sure, but you might be having same issue as here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854209/could-not-resolve-com-android-supportsupport-v421-0-0-required-by-com-twitter

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Hemal from Fabric here.

Find this in build.gradle (should be 2 instances):

> ﻿maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }

and replace with:

> maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

Comment: Hey Carlos, I just worked with the team to get that fixed, check it out!

Comment: @HemalShah This documentation is wrong repository url, fix please! https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/integrate

Comment: For those looking for FabricMC. The repo is https://maven.fabricmc.net/. Also, this Fabric  from the answer was replaced by Firebase.