# git clone S3 error: 403 Forbidden

Tags: git, amazon-s3

I want to be able to sync git repositories to AWS S3 for backups. Furthermore I want the public to be able to `git clone` my backups. [My steps](http://dabase.com/e/14002/) were:

```
s3cmd mb s3://lktesting
git update-server-info
s3cmd -P sync .git/ s3://lktesting
s3cmd ws-create s3://lktesting
s3cmd ws-info s3://lktesting
```

I thought this used to work, but now I get:

```
git clone http://lktesting.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/
Cloning into 'lktesting.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'...
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden (curl_result = 22, http_code = 403, sha1 = bf866b95d9517ea38e213740cead5cf1c313f5aa)
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git objects under `.git` may exists as single files or inside git packs. The [Git dumb HTTP protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols#The-Dumb-Protocol) will try to fetch an object as a single file, and only if this fails with "404 Not found", it will look for a pack.

Apparently, an Amazon S3 bucket will only return the 404 code if you give the "List" permission to everyone: [How do I have an S3 bucket return 404 (instead of 403) for a key that does not exist in the bucket/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037664/how-do-i-have-an-s3-bucket-return-404-instead-of-403-for-a-key-that-does-not-e)

**Update:** You can assign the necessary permission using AWS CLI with [put-bucket-acl](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-acl.html) from s3api.

Complete sequence of commands to host a clonable git repository in an S3 bucket:

```
BUCKET=my-bucket-name

# Setup
aws s3 mb s3://$BUCKET
aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket $BUCKET --acl public-read

# Sync
git update-server-info
aws s3 sync --acl public-read .git s3://$BUCKET

# Clone
git clone https://$BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you explicitly tell how to add read permissions, e.g. `aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket $BUCKET --acl public-read`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to avoid *any* sync issue (like a `.git/objects/...` missing), do not sync the content of `.git`

Use a [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) in order to copy only *one* file representing the compressed version of your git repository (see "[How can I email someone a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2545784/6309)").
That one file acts as a full-fledged git repo: you can `git clone` from it.

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git bundle create /tmp/myrepo.bundle --all
s3cmd -P sync /tmp/myrepo.bundle s3://lktesting
git clone http://lktesting.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/myrepo.bundle
```

You can not push to it though, so you might want to clone it direcly in your s3 instance, and clone from that uncompressed s3 repo.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like running the exact same approach with an empty repository works okay.

Running the same command (git clone) with debug flags[0], while I get some contents copied locally, it looks like certain objects[1] referenced in the git repo aren't present in the S3 bucket (403 is the default response code thrown when a key isn't present). Did your sync complete fully?

[0]

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git clone http://lktesting.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/
[...]
GET /objects/03/4261c96d614614344a1b618c8ec3d8d2ff7d3c HTTP/1.1
Host: lktesting.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: git/2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)
Accept: */*

* The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
```

[1] /objects/03/4261c96d614614344a1b618c8ec3d8d2ff7d3c

Comment: It would appear objects/bf/866b95d9517ea38e213740cead5cf1c313f5aa does not exist in my local or remote copy. Wonder why git is looking for it.

Comment: It looks like it's referenced in objects/pack/pack-c09c1942e51effe9e1ce1106a8f1f57f845b0dee.idx -- but I don't know enough about Git to say why.

In this case, I imagine S3's default behaviour of throwing a 403 instead of a 404 for an invalid object is causing Git's unexpected response. The clone does at least give me a repository output into `lktesting.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/`, but I don't know whether there are objects missing.