# Git clone in S3 bucket in AWS

Tags: github, amazon-s3

I am new to aws. I have an S3 bucket, I want to deploy a static website and use cloudfront for content delivery. The site's code is in a github repo. I have tried to upload the files manually, but they timeout. I am looking into cloning the repo directly in the bucket, but can't find a straightforward way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For S3 bucket, with the right permission:

```
aws s3 mb s3://$BUCKET
aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket $BUCKET --acl public-read
```

I [recommended before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34593391/6309) using [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) instead of

```
# Sync
git update-server-info
aws s3 sync --acl public-read .git s3://$BUCKET
```

Synchronizing many files is always riskier than one file.