# AWS Cloudfront returning 403 from api request to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm working on an amplify react app. From within the app, I poll an `S3 bucket` that I expect to be populated after a couple of minutes. For clarity the flow would be:

1. A user uploads a text file to `S3` and the app gets the file url in the response
2. The app then sends a request to `aws api-gateway` with the `S3 bucket` uri, which triggers a `lambda` that then calls `aws textract`, which in turn triggers a second `lambda` which writes to an `S3 bucket`. The first `lambda` returns a jobId to the app.
3. The app will then POLL an `S3 bucket` in order to get the response file using the jobId and display that file to the user.

Initially when polling the bucket, I would use the results bucket url in my api call.
This works fine when running the app locally, as the bucket url uses the `http` protocol, returning a `status code 404` until the file is created.

I then created a `cloudfront` distribution for the app, and the polling request return the error: `xhr.js:178 Mixed Content: The page at '<>my cloudfront url>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint '<my endpoint>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` which makes perfect sense.

However changing the viewer protocol behaviour in the app's cloudfront distribution from `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS` to `HTTP and HTTPS` didn't seem to work.

So I thought I could create a second cloudfront distribution for the `S3` results bucket as that uses `https`.
Yet, when I now run the api call, I get a `403 status code` and no longer the `404`.
So I tried setting up a custom error response, mapping the `403` error to `404`. I waited a good while as cloudfront can take some time, but this still doesn't seem to have made any difference.
Changing the code in my app to expect a `403` instead of a `404` works and after a while once the file has been written to the results `S3 bucket` I get the file and display it on the app. But I don't want to expect a `403` as this is entirely the wrong code for something that doesn't exist.

I have a several questions here:

1. Is this the correct approach (having a `cloudfront` distribution for the results `S3 bucket`)?
2. Why would I get a `403` when using the `cloudfront` url instead of the `404` I was getting when using the `S3` results url?
3. If point 1 is the correct approach, what do I do to fix point 2?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution seems to be, not defining the special error responses, but actually changing the S3 bucket access policy, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037664/how-do-i-have-an-s3-bucket-return-404-instead-of-403-for-a-key-that-does-not-e/19038017#19038017https://).

My bucket policy was initially:

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-results/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I then updated it to:

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-results/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PublicListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-results"
        }
    ]
}
```

This seemed to solve my issue. However it doesn't seem to explain why I would get a `404` before using cloudfront and then a `403` when using cloudfront.