# Hosting static files that supports html5mode (that needs url rewrite)

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I do not want to set up a server myself. Where can I host my static files with support of html5mode? As far as I understand it, html5mode requires url rewrite of the "fake" urls that Angular creates. Perhaps there is even a CDN with such support? Maybe Firebase Hosting supports html5mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since nobody have had any tips, I have found 2 options for hosting my static files (without having to set up a server of my on) that would support html5mode (url rewrites).

- Amazon S3. I found this tip on how to configure s3 for this purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16877231/2420037
- Firebase Hosting. They are very soon launching support for url rewrite. And you do not need to use Firebase as your data store. And they use a CDN, so you are very available around the world with the static files for your Next Big Thing.

The second option is 100% what I was searching for, so therefore I will end this question by answering it myself.