# Angular 2 and aws, routes not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, angular, amazon-s3

In try to deploy me angular 2 app on amozon web hosting.
the index page works well but when I try to acces other pages like `/users` I got a `404 not found` error.

I try to follow this post [Configure Amazon S3 static site with Angular JS ui.router html5Mode(true) on page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063945/configure-amazon-s3-static-site-with-angular-js-ui-router-html5modetrue-on-pag) without success.

here my app http://ugram-team-7.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

config your app route to use hash #

```
const routes: Routes = [
  // routes here
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ... other imports
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // .../#/users/
  ],
  ...
})
export class SomeModule { }
```

**or configure S3**

In the **Edit Redirection Rules** section of the S3 Console for your domain, add the following rules:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HostName>domain.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>#/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

put this in index.html

```
<script language="javascript"> 
if (typeof(window.history.pushState) == 'function') { 
  window.history.pushState(null, "Site Name", window.location.hash.substring(2)); 
} else { 
  window.location.hash = window.location.hash.substring(2); 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: i'm glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem and still use URL Rewriting.

First of all you should not distribute your website directly from S3 but placing a CloudFront distribution in front of it.

Create a custom Error Page rule on the CloudFront distribution with the following:

- HTTP Error Code: 404
- Error Caching Minimum TTL (seconds): 0
- Customize Error Response: Yes
- Response Page Path: /index.html
- HTTP Response Code: 200

Please also [take a look at my guide](https://medium.com/@coorasse/deploy-angular2-on-amazons3-5bbc040ab64a) for a detailed explanation.