# Angular Route not working when deployed on aws ec2(ubuntu)

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, routes

I made a angular frontend application and deployed on aws .Now this app is working alright on local machine but when deployed on aws and i tried to run using my domain name(using nginx) only index.html is showing and its not routing forward.
ps:-the config file is fine as my other sample app(basic bootstrap) is running fine.

Comment: have you set correct `<base-path>` in index.html for your root of app. from that location your app will going to load. This would be your `project name/RootFolder/your-router`

Comment: i dont think anything is wrong with the code as "ng serve" is working fine and my app is running on localHost.. Its when i deploy on server that i get the issue

Comment: go to aws.. see from where your root folder is..  and check `index.html` file.. all router is served from base-path.. and you have to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059850/angular-2-and-aws-routes-not-found

Comment: https://medium.com/@sandeeptengale/deploy-angular-app-on-aws-ec2-instance-20749f17b33e

Comment: is domain.com/index.html working fine ?  in my project we have hosted on aws s3 bucket. There also we are doing same thing