# How to disconnect ssh connection by using node-ssh in node js

Tags: node.js

Can anyone help me, how t disconnect ssh connection using node-ssh module in node js. Also how to handle error.

my code is

```
 driver = require('node-ssh');

    ssh = new driver({
              host: '192.168.*.*',
              username: 'user',
              password: 'password',
              privateKey : require('fs').readFileSync('/tmp/my_key')
            });

    ssh.connect().then(function() {
           /*
       some code
        */

            },function(error) {
                console.log(error);

    });
```

Pls help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'node-ssh' wrapper doesn't seem to provide an 'end' function, or a way to access the underlying ssh2 connection object. That leaves you with a couple options:

Fork the [source](https://github.com/steelbrain/node-ssh), write an 'end' method, and issue a pull request to the node-ssh wrapper so that future users can use the wrapper and end the connections. Alternatively, you can create an [issue](https://github.com/steelbrain/node-ssh/issues/new) and wait for someone else to create the functionality if/when they deem it necessary.

Use the underlying [ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) library instead. It exposes a lot more functionality to you, including an 'end' method, to close the connection, but uses callbacks instead of promises, which would require you to refactor your code.

Additionally, you could add the following to your code, though this is **very heavily not recommended**, as it's messing with a prototype you don't own and could ruin compatibility with future versions of the node-ssh module:

```
driver.prototype.end = function() {
  this.Connection.end()
  this.Connected = false
}
```

you can then call `ssh.end()` to close the connection.

Answer (score 15):

Use the `dispose` method. Example:

```
const node_ssh = require('node-ssh');
const ssh = new node_ssh();

ssh.connect({
  host: 'XXX',
  username: 'YYY',
  privateKey: 'ZZZ'
}).then(resp => {
  console.log(resp);
  ssh.dispose();
});
```

Comment: @AmauryD Accepted answers are a joke anyways, they almost never change and are often not the best solution... example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267339/s3-static-website-hosting-route-all-paths-to-index-html

Answer (score 2):

I've asked directly the creator of the library, here i report the answer:

"Note: If anything of the ssh2 object is not implemented and I am taking more time than I should, You can always use `MySSH.Connection.close()`"

[Issue#9](https://github.com/steelbrain/node-ssh/issues/9#event-311579970)

Then he has done a commit and now you have your method!

```
ssh.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggle for these the ssh to a remote server frequently, and the connection can not be closed by `ssh.compose()` in the ssh-node package, and I find remote windows ssh server still generate many processes named `sshd` process and not be closed, and after `ssh.compose`, the node.js will throw the error `Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead` which can not be caught by code.I find many references, it could be the `TCP` connection is still working on and not be closed. So I try to refer to the ssh-node code and use the

`ssh.connection.destroy()`

which point to the `Client.prototype.destroy` method in `ssh2` package， so the error `Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead` will disappeared, and the connection will be closed totally.

Answer (score 0):

So what worked for me was basically destroying the ssh-client's connection before disposing the connection.
Take a look at the following code

```
    // Create an SSH Client
    const ssh = new NodeSSH();
    
    // Establish a connection to the ssh server
    const connection = await ssh.connect({
        username: 'username', // username of the main server
        host: 'ipaddress', // ip address of the main server
        password: 'password'
    })


    // Run the command on the ssh server
    const response = await connection.execCommand('commandToRun')
    console.log('Response: ', response.stdout)

    if (connection.isConnected()) console.log(' Connection is alive; Disposing the connection')
    // destroy the ssh client connection
    ssh.connection?.destroy()
    // dispose the connection
    connection.dispose()

    if (!connection.isConnected()) console.log('Connection is successfully disposed')
```

You should see the following logs:

```
 Connection is alive; Disposing the connection
✅ Connection is successfully disposed
```