# S3 Static Website Hosting redirect with QueryString

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3

I'm currently using this solution to host my angular application on AWS S3 using Html5Mode: [S3 Static Website Hosting Route All Paths to Index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267339/s3-static-website-hosting-route-all-paths-to-index-html/16877231#16877231)

My problem is that I want to keep the querystring during the redirection:

`http://domain.org/posts?order=2` currently redirect to `http://domain.org/#!/posts`

I want it to go to `http://domain.org/#!/posts?order=2`.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Something like this? http://serverfault.com/a/633571/153161

Comment: This is the same solution as the one I've already put in place, it completely ignore querystring parameters, which is my issue :(

Comment: Are you sure?  http://spa-redirect-test.sqlbot.net/posts?this=works+for+me (actual test site, feel free to click).

Comment: Now i'm upset, this works but i don't know why it wasn't before -_-
Thx a lot for your help !

Comment: Possibly because you had been trying `!#` instead of `#!`.  (That's how you showed it in the question, but I assumed you intended the opposite).

Comment: Also, it is customary, here, when someone works you towards a solution through clarifying comments, to offer them the opportunity to post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

This probably happens because you don't [forward the query strings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/QueryStringParameters.html) from CloudFront to the S3 static website.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to set the querystring first, then your hash fragment.

```
/?order=2#!/posts
```

Anything after # is not sent to the server. I know it seems the opposite of what you are trying to achieve, but this is how things work. QueryString parameters are sent to the server. Hash fragments are not and a QueryString in the hash fragment is still part of the hash fragment, so it is not transferred to the server.