# Deploying angular2 web app on google cloud buckets

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-platform

So to deploy angular2 app we simply upload all production files to a bucket just as described [here. (deploy static website)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#uploading_your_sites_files).

But how can we redirect all urls to `index.html` so that angular2 router can take care of them. We can set `Main Page` from `website configuration` of bucket. But we cannot specify that all urls should redirect to `index.html`.

Currently any url other than `Main Page` results in 404 page not found.

There is [similar question on SO for amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267339/s3-static-website-hosting-route-all-paths-to-index-html), but cannot find one for google cloud.

Comment: Maybe you should share your current app configuration?

Comment: configuration of angular2 app..??

Comment: this is uploaded to simple google cloud bucket. Like uploading angular2 production folder from google buckets UI, there is no configuration for google app engine involved.

Comment: Ah, I was thrown off by the google-app-engine tag :)

Comment: @DanCornilescu Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: I was able to solve this problem using a hack. Posted an answer.

Comment: @Nag: I haven't tried. hhsadiq's answer looks good.

Comment: People may want to try using the new hash location strategy to solve this problem https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this issue by using a hack, not sure what the proper way to do this. But atleast this worked.

1. Open storage in `console.cloud.google.com`. [image]
2. Click edit website configuration in buckets listing. Click far right in row with three dots. And select `edit configuratione` [image]
3. Enter your main page same as 404 page. The angular routing will work fine this way. [image]

Comment: The issue with @hhsadiq is that the initial get request is going to return a 404 HTTP code, it is going to render the page, but with that error, that affects SEO a lot and if you set that application URL in a Google Ads campaign it is going to fail because of that.