# How serve the same file with dynamic URLs over a AWS CDN?

Tags: angularjs, express, amazon-s3, cdn

I have a Angular App with a lot of routes, that run over a Express Server.

Since all routes are from the same one-page-application, I configured Express the return always the same `index.html` for a bunch of routes, like `/login` and `/settings`. And I also have custom routes like `/user/:userId`.

But since we remove our backend logic to a separated API, we plan to move our files into a Amazon CDN, CloudFront.

But the thing is, CDN works like directories, there is a way to configure CloudFront to point all request **without extension** to return the `index.html`? Because that way all `.js` and `.css` would work nicely.

I appreciate any help! Thanks.

**Update 1**

I did some more digging into Aws, and apparently this is more a S3 configuration than CloudFront. But I still don't know how to do this.

**Update 2**

I already found the answer in [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267339/s3-static-website-hosting-route-all-paths-to-index-html).

The solution is tricky, I just had to configure all 404 errors (403 in the case of S3) to redirect to the `index.html` returning the status code 200, and all worked fine.

Comment: CDN are for static files. Do you mean index.html is a template with dynamic content of home and settings route ?

Comment: No, all my files are statics, also `index.html`. The views (home, settings) are loaded dynamically with Angular Route.

Comment: As noted in your update, you can't move files "into" CloudFront.  CloudFront is a cache -- it has no persistent storage.  You still need to store them on an origin server, somewhere -- commonly, this is S3.  CloudFront doesn't interpret URLs, it passes them through to the origin server.  This seems to be a case where you are asking one question, but you may actually need to be asking a different question altogether.

Comment: Yes @Michael-sqlbot, you're right. In fact I already found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267339/s3-static-website-hosting-route-all-paths-to-index-html)