# Deploying reactjs based application to AWS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have deployed a ReactJS based application to AWS S3 bucket. Additionally, I had to use CloudFront due to react-router issues, please see [S3 Static Website Hosting Route All Paths to Index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267339/s3-static-website-hosting-route-all-paths-to-index-html).
Now, with CloudFront I have to re-create the distribution when I change endpoints (e.g. API host, callback URL etc), is this the way it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't have to re-create Cloudfront distribution.

A common practice is to append a hash to the static asset, eg:

```
<script src="myapp.bundle.js?v=12345678"></script>
```

The hash is usually the MD5/SHA1 hash of the file. Some may use the timestamp of the time you build the code. So after you update the file content and issue a new deploy, a new hash should be used. Consider the following flow as the client:

1. A client requests for `myapp.bundle.js?v=1`
2. Cache does not exist yet, Cloudfront proxies the request to S3 directly and caches the content.
3. Cloudfront serves cached content to `myapp.bundle.js?v=1` for any subsequent requests.
4. Now you updated your code and deployed to S3 (with a new hash in your index.html).
5. Clients now request `myapp.bundle.js?v=2` instead
6. repeat 2-3 and so on

The hash appending is usually done by build tool such as [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) with plugins.

Comment: This actually makes sense, I would like to try. I used create-react-app, do you know what changes I need to make to have the bundle version?

Comment: I believe it is doing so for you already https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js#L74

Comment: I checked, it is adding a hash code into the js files, but I don't see that the hash value is changing.

Comment: Consider asking this with another question. Original question is more on Cloudfront.

Comment: CRA already appends a hash. The hash value changes if source code changes.

Answer (score 0):

To make this solution complete, create-react-app uses HtmlWebpackPlugin to inject script tag into the index.html file. 
To append a hash, change the node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.prod.js as below (added hash:true line)

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
      },
      hash:true
    }),
```

To see the details, please see the documentation
https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#configuration

Comment: No, you don't need to add anything like this to Create React App. It already adds the hash.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be the one which is written here https://medium.com/@omgwtfmarc/if-youre-not-already-doing-this-creating-an-invalidation-for-cloudfront-will-dramatically-speed-7080357c9e8d

Just add invalidation for /index.html