# AWS S3 Bucket Url to Custom Domain link

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

We are hosting a static Angular 2 website on Amazon S3.

Our app is deployed at http://abc.domain.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

I'm getting HTTPS not secure warning.
Also I want to make abc.domain.s3.amazonaws.com => custom url "abc.domain.com"

We also have SSL certificate for "abc.domain.com"

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  Help by voting and accepting answer if its works.

Comment: if you faced issue while reload or refresh angular app here is help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299204/receive-accessdenied-when-trying-to-access-a-reload-or-refresh-or-one-in-new-tab/50302276#50302276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step to do this :

**Solution 1**: if want direct S3 and domain to be link :

1. Create Route53 entry and select S3 domain as alias from drop down.

**Solution 2** : if want https for your domain

1. Get Certificate from "AWS Certificate manager"
2. Validate domain in "AWS Certificate Manager"
3. Create cloud front for that domain using certificate.
4. Create domain entry in Route53 and select as alias from drop dowan this CloudFront URL

**Note** : Creating cloudfront and reflecting take almost 30-60 minutes. Also certificate activation takes time.

[image]

Certificate help : https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/
Cloudfront creation : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/