# Cloudfront gives "Access denied" when accessing index document

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 website configured to be used as a static website, and a Cloudfront distribution with the S3 bucket as the origin.

My index files are called `index` and I have specified this as the index files in both the bucket configuration and the Cloudfront distribution configuration.

[image]

[image]

However if I go to https://example.com/directory/ I get an error document as follows, where the RequestID and HostID change on each request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>7F09A18821FE70FD</RequestId><HostId>H5OR+AZpNSGlhrUX1ECegTbWkio728A1MIdGkO4bkCZIJa/XQ6Uv7Hu0GgNgyxL+snerPPDnzr8=</HostId></Error>
```

If I go to https://example.com/directory/index then the page shows correctly.

If I access the website from either the cloudfront URL or the S3 website endpoint, rather than my custom domain, then the problem does not happen.

How can I get the directory index pages to be served correctly when accessing the S3 bucket?

Comment: Add .html to the document name.

Comment: s3 website hosting serve only .html content. U can server as example.com/directory/index/ but inside index/index.html folder has to present for other folder.

Comment: @aviboy2006 S3 can serve whatever file names you want, with whatever MIME types you want.

Comment: Agree. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299204/receive-accessdenied-when-trying-to-access-a-reload-or-refresh-or-one-in-new-tab/50302276#50302276  this setting

Comment: Please provide the entire error response, not just "Access Denied."

Comment: have you try link which i given in above comment ?

Comment: @hephalump Unfortunately I don't want to do that for reasons.

Comment: @aviboy2006 That is for a different use case. I don't want to show the same page for whichever URL the user visits. I just want to change the name of my index files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the origin for the distribution from `<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com` to `<bucket-name>.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com` fixed the issue.

Unfortunately when I started typing in the dropdown in the Origin settings, Amazon started to suggest S3 buckets, and it suggested the bucket using the first format.