# Why AWS SSL certificate or cloudfront is crashing my Angular website

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have deployed an Angular web site to an AWS using an S3 bucket for static web hosting, Route53, an Amazon SSL certificate and cloudfront.
The main domain name will work ie "mysite.com" , but if I have a sign on error or refresh a page with for example "mysite.com/auth" or "mysite.com/shops" I get "access denied" and I can not view my site.

The S3 bucket is public access and I have granted public access to all the objects in it.

I have requested an Amazon certificate for this site mysite.com and [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) and *.mysite.com.

I have created a cloudfront distribution using the certificate created above  and added mysite.com and [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) as alternate domains.

I have use the cloudfront option to create the cname records in Route53.

As mentioned above the domain name mysite.com works but if a path is appended like /auth I get access denied.

This is drivin me mad so any help would be appreciated I am sure the solution is simple but I can not find it anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anything special about these paths (such as a different origin)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299204/receive-accessdenied-when-trying-to-access-a-reload-or-refresh-or-one-in-new-tab see this answer help you. Details here https://www.internetkatta.com/host-angular-2-or-4-or-5-version-in-aws-s3-using-cloudfront

Comment: Wow thanks for your prompt reaction. No nothing special they are using the same origin

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you the above reply solved my problem

Comment: Thanks again
The reply above was the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299204/receive-accessdenied-when-trying-to-access-a-reload-or-refresh-or-one-in-new-tab