# AWS S3 Bucket - Access Denied on Sub-Pages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

So I have an AWS S3 Bucket hosting the files for a react application I've built. I use CodePipeline to build and compile the React app and store the files on an S3 bucket which is served through a CloudFront CDN.

Everything seems to be working fine when I access the url from the root `https://website.com`. When I click "login" on that page I get directed to the following route `https://website.com/auth/login` and it works awesome.

**The Problem**
If I try to access the page `https://website.com/auth/login` directly I get the following error:

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>66CE67E2E5DA0B7B</RequestId>
  <HostId>Spfhgnlygx05eugycEy5ew4e8oSn/ccNX21Iy/6qaAxI8glXljDjgKmUPvMzRd8+NktQsNietpg=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I set the default resource in the cloudfront CDN to the `/index.html` which is why the root domain works, but how do I get all there urls to point to `/index.html` so the app routes it properly?

Comment: Did you [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218979/react-router-doesnt-work-in-aws-s3-bucket) the 'Error document' in S3 bucket static website hosting to index.html?

Comment: So oddly enough even if I do that it does not work. Now if I use the Amazon URL for the bucket it works (Bypassing the CDN) http://website.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/auth/login ... but If i go through the CDN it breaks as mentioned above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299204/receive-accessdenied-when-trying-to-access-a-reload-or-refresh-or-one-in-new-tab/50302276#50302276 try this you have to setup custom error page in Cloudfront. https://www.internetkatta.com/host-angular-2-or-4-or-5-version-in-aws-s3-using-cloudfront

Comment: above link will solve your issue. @DigitalMC

Comment: Don’t forget upvote question and answer. Thanks good to know it’s help you.

Comment: I have already given its solution. Please refer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218979/react-router-doesnt-work-in-aws-s3-bucket/71591815#71591815

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to set a rule for 403 Forbidden in my cloudfront configuration as posted here: [Receive AccessDenied when trying to access a reload or refresh or one in new tab in angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299204/receive-accessdenied-when-trying-to-access-a-reload-or-refresh-or-one-in-new-tab/50302276#50302276)