# refreshing the page results in 404 error- AWS - Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5, angular6, angular4-router

I am building an application with the help of Angular6 and having problem in routing. All the routes are working when I click on a particular tab but whenever I refresh the current page, it is throwing 404 error. I tried Hashtag location strategy but getting # in URl. Is there any other way to implement without hash strategy. Currently application is hosted in AWS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: 404 error occur when I refresh through the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-the-browser)

Answer (score 2):

one work around is adding index.html in error document section but it isn't recommended.

[image]

check other solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16877231/4899523).

Comment: Yep, the only solution I figured out is this one, adding index.html in the error document,  cause angular router needs to resolve any route to return to the index.html, see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-the-browser

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Deployment section in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) if you are using EC2.
The webserver you are using must handle those requests:

> If the app uses the Angular router, you must configure the server to
>   return the application's host page (index.html) when asked for a file
>   that it does not have.
>   A routed application should support "deep links". A deep link is a URL
>   that specifies a path to a component inside the app. For example,
>   http://someurl/heroes/42 is a deep link to the hero detail page
>   that displays the hero with id: 42.

Are you using any webserver such as Apache or Nginx?

Comment: Thank for your quick response. No. I am not using Apache or Nginx

Comment: And how are you serving the application? What service are you using?

Comment: serving with AWS

Comment: AWS has innumerous services and many of them can be used to serve static html applications (EC2, S3, etc). You should tell us which u are using.

Comment: Christian Benseler AWS S3 service.