# Unable to load ReactJS with url segments in aws s3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My ReactJS project is hosted in the AWS S3 and is working fine for the default `/` url. When I added a login page with url `/login` is working in my `localhost:3000` but getting some error in S3.

My error screenshot is below. Should I add any settings or configuration in S3? I have only basic knowledge in S3 and hence this question. Hope anyone can help me..
[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you check if the S3 file permissions are not public?

Comment: Should I check for the project folder in the bucket or any particular file inside that?

Comment: @Hareesh This should work for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/16877231/1188322

Comment: @kiranvj This does not fix my issues.