# React build, but index.html is empty or 404page

Tags: reactjs

I looked up a lot of other materials,
but I couldn't find a solution, so I left a ask.

I did a react build, but the page appears empty or the 404 error page is shown...
I don't know what the problem is.

The contents I tried are as follows.

1. in package.json, I added homepage": "./"

and my App.js code  is here

```
~~
return (
        <BrowserRouter history={history}>
            {/* <ThemeProvider theme={theme} /> */}
            {/* <Router history={history}></Router> */}
            <Switch>
{* ~~ hide *}
               <Route path="/admin/vol/upload" exact component={Auth(VolUpload, true, true)} />
               <Route path="/admin/board/upload" exact component={Auth(BoardUpload, true, true)} />
               <Route path="/admin/vol/apply" exact component={Auth(VolApplyManage, true, true)} />
{* hide ~~ *}
              <Route path="*" component={ErrPage} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
};

export default App;
```

and after build i can only see ErrPage component...
what is the problem in my code.

plz help me ㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠ

Comment: what do you mean by **in package.json, I added homepage": "./"**. Can you paste your `package.json` here also.

Comment: I see.....ㅠㅠㅠ
I'll try to upload related files.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem? Looks like my app has a problem like this too

Comment: it's worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267339/s3-static-website-hosting-route-all-paths-to-index-html