# Add context root to a single page react app hosted on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, azure-static-web-app

I have single page react app on AWS (content being served from S3 origin through cloud front distribution via registered public domain name). We are wanting to add a context root to the url that is being used to get to the index.html (so the app).
*Current url* - `https://host.com/init`
*Desired url* - `https://host.com/contextRoot/init`

What are the ideas to achieve this type of url (with context root)? I believe the context root can not be added/mapped in cloud front or the public domain registry itself. If that is the case, what are the options ? Suggestions please.

The use case is that callers of the app come in with that context root in the url.

Comment: I'm not clear do you want to redirect https://host.com to https://host.com/contextRoot?

Comment: The callers of the app come in with that context root in the url.

Comment: Add `/contextRoot/` to the prefix of all the objects in the S3 bucket. In other words: create that "folder" in S3 and move all your files into it. Otherwise, you'll have to place CloudFront in front off the S3 bucket, and use a custom origin path configuration, or maybe a CloudFront function or Lambda@Edge to rewrite the origin path. Changing the actual paths in S3 to match the requests coming in is by far the easiest fix.

Answer (score 0):

The best as well as a multitude of other options are listed here :- [S3 Static Website Hosting Route All Paths to Index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267339/s3-static-website-hosting-route-all-paths-to-index-html?rq=2). My own research says that domain host or the cloud front distribution can not be updated to have a custom context root defined. Instead the app needs to handle through one or more of functions (I call them tricks) listed in the above link to handle the request.