# single-page-application routing is not working after deploying to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, micro-frontend, single-spa, single-spa-angular, single-spa-react

Root application and other MFE's are deployed to s3 bucket.
I am able to load the first page (`"/"`) of the application, but if I navigate to other page it throws error not found.
I have used `microfrontend-layout` to define the `single-spa-router`

Microfrontend-layout.html

```html
  <application name="@TEST/app1"></application>
  <main>
    <route path="/" exact>
      <application name="@TEST/app2"></application>
    </route>
    <route path="/contact">
      <application name="@TEST/app3"></application>
    </route>
    <route path="/angular">
      <application name="angular-app"></application>
    </route>
    <route path="/mfe1">
      <application name="@TEST/mfe1"></application>
    </route>
    <route path="/app4">
      <application name="@TEST/app4"></application>
    </route>
    <route default>
      <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
      <application name="@TEST/"></application>
    </route>
  </main>
</single-spa-router>
```

Route-config.js

```js
import { registerApplication, start } from "single-spa";
import * as singleSpa from 'single-spa';
import {
  constructApplications,
  constructRoutes,
  constructLayoutEngine,
} from "single-spa-layout";
import microfrontendLayout from "./microfrontend-layout.html";

const routes = constructRoutes(microfrontendLayout);
const applications = constructApplications({
  routes,
  loadApp({ name }) {
    return System.import(name);
  },
});
const layoutEngine = constructLayoutEngine({ routes, applications });

applications.forEach(registerApplication);

layoutEngine.activate();

start();
```

I am running `yarn run build` to create my "dist" folder and upload it in the bucket manually without any `.yml` file/pipeline.

I guess the route is not working when deployed.

Locally it is working perfectly.

Is there anything that needs to be added before deployment?

this is my folder structure

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16877231/271415).

Comment: @jarmod i tried adding routerrules still the same issue

Comment: @jarmod here is my routerrules.json

{
  "IndexDocument": {
    "Suffix": "index.html"
  },
  "RoutingRules": [
    {
      "Condition": {
        "HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals": "404"
      },
      "Redirect": {
        "HostName": "testui.s3-website.localhost.localstack.cloud",
        "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "#/"
      }
    }
  ]
}