Issue with 404 Error for Sub Paths in Deployed Frontend React Application
[Tech : ReactJS]
Problem Description
After building and deploying my frontend application, I'm encountering a 404 error when trying to access subpaths directly. However, accessing the main domain (example.in) works fine. For example, attempting to visit example.in/login directly results in a 404 error, but removing /login and visiting example.in first, then navigating to login through the application, works as expected.
Example Scenario

Directly accessing a subpath like example.in/certificate/1/ results in a 404 error.
Accessing the main domain (example.in) and navigating to the certificate page step by step (example.in/certificate/2/) works correctly.

Observation
It seems that accessing subpaths directly leads to 404 errors, while navigating through the application works as expected. This behavior is confusing, and I'm unsure of the underlying cause.
Request for Assistance
I'm seeking guidance on identifying and resolving the issue causing the 404 errors for directly accessed subpaths. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Attempts:

Tried deploying the application using AWS S3, ACM (AWS Certificate Manager), and CloudFront, encountering the same 404 errors.
Attempted deployment using Vercel, but encountered similar issues.

Expected Outcome:
I expected that after addressing the above points, the issue of receiving 404 errors when accessing subpaths directly would be resolved. Specifically, I anticipated that:

Directly accessing subpaths like /login or /certificate/1/ would successfully load the corresponding pages without encountering 404 errors.
The application would handle routing correctly, regardless of whether users access pages directly or navigate through the application.


The server has to be setup such that all paths /* serve the root index.html. Google around "server html5 pushstate config". Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35673266/1086398 for config of cloudfront solution with s3.

For Vercel Deployment:
Add a vercel.json file to your project root with the following content:
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/index.html" }]
}

This configuration ensures that all requests are directed to index.html, allowing React Router to handle routing correctly.
For AWS CloudFront Deployment:

Navigate to the CloudFront distribution settings.
Go to Error Pages.
Click Create custom error response.
In the Error response section:

Enter 400 for the HTTP error code.
Set the Error caching minimum TTL to 10.
Keep Customize error response unchecked.
Set Response page path to /index.html.
Choose 200: OK for HTTP Response code.


Click Create to save the custom error response.

This configuration ensures that CloudFront returns index.html for all 404 errors, allowing React Router to handle routing correctly.
Expected Outcome
After applying the above solutions:

Directly accessing subpaths like /login or /certificate/1/ should load the corresponding pages without 404 errors.
The application should handle routing correctly, regardless of whether users access pages directly or navigate through the application.

Conclusion
By following the provided steps, you should be able to resolve the issue of receiving 404 errors when accessing subpaths directly in your ReactJS application deployed on Vercel or AWS CloudFront. If you have any more better  solution let us know.
Keep Learning :)
